# If $X$ is any arbitrary random variable, is it always true that if $P(X \leq b) = 1$ and $P(X \geq a) = 1$, that $P(a \leq X \leq b) = 1$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is any random variable in the most general sense. If I know that the events $\{X \geq a\}$ and $\{X \leq b\}$ occur almost surely, i.e.:

$$
P(X \leq b) = 1 \ \ \text{and} \ \ P(X \geq a) = 1,
$$

does it automatically imply that $P(a \leq X \leq b) = 1$?

Comment: Yes. The event $(a \leq X \leq b$) is the intersection of the events $X\geq a$ and $X\leq b$. As this two events have probability one, their intersection has probability one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The complement of the event $\{a\leq X\leq b\}$ is $\{X<a\}\cup \{X>b\}$, and
$$ \mathbb{P}(\{X<a\}\cup \{X>b\})\leq \mathbb{P}(X<a)+\mathbb{P}(X>b)=0+0=0 $$
by hypothesis, hence $\mathbb{P}(a\leq X\leq b)=1$.

Comment: Can I ask if the two events $\{X \geq a\}$ and $\{X \leq b\}$ independent or disjoint or neither?

Comment: If $a<b$ then $\{X\geq a\}\cap \{X\leq b\}=\{a\leq X\leq b\}$, which may or may not be empty, depending on $X$ and the values of $a$ and $b$. In general they won't be independent either.